# Unable to validate bootstrap 4 custom-radio with Parsley.js

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, parsley.js

I use parsley to validate my form `<input>, <select>` and it works great, but when i work with `<input type="radio">` i have some issue. this is how i get my output. As you can see other two options are not listed with `text-invalid`.

[image]

As show in image other two option are not hilighted with `text-invalid`. I even added `required` to other two radio input but nothing works.

**Here is my code: With quick demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#adform").parsley({
    errorClass: "is-invalid text-danger",
    successClass: "is-valid",
    errorsWrapper: '<div class="form-group"></div>',
    errorTemplate: '<small class="form-text text-danger"></small>'
  }).on("form:submit", function() {
    $("#submiting").modal("show"), $(".st").css("display", "none")
  })
}), $(".selectpicker").attr("data-trigger", "change").attr("data-required", "true");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.9.1/parsley.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="adform" role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" data-parsley-validate>
  <label class="text-black-50">Fuel Type<b class="text-danger ml-1">*</b></label>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
    <span class="border p-2 shadow-sm rounded">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="diesel" name="fue" class="custom-control-input" value="Diesel" required data-parsley-error-message="Select fuel type" data-parsley-errors-container="#fuelerr">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="diesel">Diesel</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="petrol" name="fue" class="custom-control-input" value="Petrol">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="petrol">Petrol</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="hybrid" name="fue" class="custom-control-input" value="Hybrid">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="hybrid">Hybrid</label>
        </div>
    </span>
    <div id="fuelerr" class="pt-2"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Ad" />
</form>
```

con some one help me solve this, How do i make other two option to be highlighted with `text-invalid or text-danger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since input code is wrapped with separate divs , the error class is not getting applied, So you need to make of classLoader like below.

```
classHandler: function (el) {
        return el.$element.closest('.fuel-type');
    }
```

and add fuel-type class to

```
<span class="border p-2 shadow-sm rounded fuel-type">
```

Check out following demo, hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#adform").parsley({
    errorClass: "is-invalid text-danger",
    successClass: "is-valid",
    classHandler: function (el) {
        return el.$element.closest('.fuel-type');
    },
    errorsWrapper: '<div class="form-group"></div>',
    errorTemplate: '<small class="form-text text-danger"></small>'
  }).on("form:submit", function() {
    $("#submiting").modal("show"), $(".st").css("display", "none")
  })
}), $(".selectpicker").attr("data-trigger", "change").attr("data-required", "true");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.9.1/parsley.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="adform" role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" data-parsley-validate>
  <label class="text-black-50">Fuel Type<b class="text-danger ml-1">*</b></label>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
    <span class="border p-2 shadow-sm rounded fuel-type">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="diesel" name="fue" class="custom-control-input" value="Diesel" required data-parsley-error-message="Select fuel type" data-parsley-errors-container="#fuelerr">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="diesel">Diesel</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="petrol" name="fue" class="custom-control-input" value="Petrol">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="petrol">Petrol</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="hybrid" name="fue" class="custom-control-input" value="Hybrid">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="hybrid">Hybrid</label>
        </div>
    </span>
    <div id="fuelerr" class="pt-2"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Ad" />
</form>
```

Comment: Great it work. What about other inputs, like `text` and `<select >` and if I add label inside `<div class ="fuel-type">` will it show error

Comment: Yup , may be you can try out.

Comment: So the `classHandler` is for radio button ?

Comment: No, that is for any element, If you want to set success/error classes, you can make use of that. here is the doc reference http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html#section-17